# How to represent an alternate key in Entity-Relationship Model?

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, entity-relationship

If there is a relation between two entities that makes use of the primary keys of both entities, and you want to use other attributes of one of the entities to act as an alternate key, how would that be modeled?

I guess what I'm having trouble modeling is the equivalent of an 'OR' statement. Either the relationship requires the primary key, or it requires two or more particular attributes to serve as an alternate key for that entity.

Comment: What is the cardinality of the relation?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to add an 'OR' in a relational model is to add another linking table that models the relation based on the alternative keys. To get all related rows, you query by linking thought the 'primary-keys linking table' and query by linking through the 'alternative-keys linking table' and union the results.